# could not read Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com'

Tags: python, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-source-repositories

I am trying to install private python library in gcr.io container and getting the error message even after setting configure-docker for gcloud and --network=cloudbuild in  yaml file.

RUN pip install -e git+https://source.developers.google.com/p/project_name/r/github_domain_repository_name#egg=package_path

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['auth', 'configure-docker']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--network=cloudbuild', '-t', 'gcr.io/project-${_ENVIRONMENT}/cloud_run-pubsub_example', './cloud-run/file_upserter/']
```

Comment: Is the Source Repository in a different GCP Project from the Cloud Build instance?

Comment: No. It's in same project.